# What should be the Custom Action Condition if I only want it to run during Upgrade?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I create my msi using wix and now I have situation where I want to run my custom action only on upgrade from older version to newer version.I have tried UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE as the condition but it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

`UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE` is set in the context of the uninstallation of the prior version. What you are looking for is the property used as the [Action Property of your Major Upgrade](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372379). It appears the [MajorUpgrade element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/majorupgrade.html) sets `WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED` as well (perhaps as the action property).

Comment: What is the sequence while upgrading a product to another version?First it is upgraded and then the older version is uninstalled Or is it the other way around.  I basically want my custom action to delete certain files of older version before it puts the new files .What condition should I use?

Comment: That is at the default position i.e at the end.

Comment: My apologies for the lack of clarity in my previous comment: the behavior is controlled by when [RemoveExistingProducts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371197) is sequenced. If you want to change the behavior, change the sequencing. (If you want further details, search for or ask another question, assuming it's not a duplicate.)